# Render picture with alpha in webpage

Tags: css, textures

Is there a way to render background texture with alpha in a webpage? I want to have texture on top of a gradient so I can see through it.

I'm not using canvas for this (although I do use canvas for some other animation effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with CSS3 Multiple Backgrounds and CSS3 Gradients. Here is a [good article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/multiple-bg-css-gradients) on the subject.

**Edit**: To clarify, you basically need to just define two backgrounds on the object. First one would be the gradient while the second would be the alpha texture.

Comment: This isn't supported before IE9.

Comment: @JezenThomas Yes it isn't. But its generally a good idea now to use fall backs for browsers which don't support modern features instead of degrading the experience for the majority who can actually see them.

Comment: Agreed, but this problem is easy enough to solve without CSS3.

Comment: Does the texture has to be alpha texture (transparent) in the first place? I only have this opaque texture and I place it on the bottom and use transparent gradient on the top (rgba color), but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @ryf9059 Didn't you originally say that you want to render a texture with alpha? The only way to see through a texture is that it has an alpha transparency channel.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need CSS3 for this. Use a seamless background tile on `html` and an alpha gradient on the `body`.

```
html {background: #fff url(path/to/bg-tile.png) repeat 0 0;}
body {background: transparent url(path/to/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 0;}
```

[Multiple background images are not supported in IE<9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds)

Comment: what's the `transparent` key word for? Doesn't seems to work for me, should I declare an alpha for it?

Comment: That's part of the [CSS background shorthand declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp). It sets the background color. What do you mean by “declare an alpha”?

Comment: by declare an alpha I mean to assign a value for it, since my texture is not transparent which should have an default alpha of 1, but the transparent here doesn't provide an alpha which confuses me.

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but are you assuming that you can use CSS to set an opacity level on a background image? Because that *isn't* what I'm talking about. My approach is very straight forward; on the bottom layer, you have an opaque tile. Above that, you have a repeating gradient. The gradient transitions from opaque to transparent. *The alpha channel is already in the image*.

Comment: If it was my answer that helped you, you could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a big div as background and add the gradient and the png inside the div and then use css to resize and position